# Install not signed driver in Windows 2019 with no prompt

Tags: windows-server-2019, drivers, digital-signatures, azure-devops

I want to install the not signed driver in the Azure DevOps pipeline (*windows-2019* image).

Driver is in the form of the *.inf* file. On the local machine i am using the following command:

```
pnputil -i -a driver_name.inf
```

but it shows a security prompt. Is there a way to turn it off?

Edit:
Prompt looks like this:

[image: Would you like to install this device software?]

Comment: Du you mean the UAC prompt?

Answer (score 2):

You get that prompt because the driver publisher is not thrusted bu your server.

You can pre-add Novell as a thrusted publisher to remove such warning in your case.

> The Client uses Microsoft Authenticode digital signatures to verify
> Novell, Inc. as the publisher of Client drivers, as is required by the
> latest versions of Windows. During the Client installation, Windows
> presents an approval dialog box which lets you confirm whether
> software from Publisher: Novell, Inc. should be installed.
>
> An Always trust software from Novell, Inc. option is also available.
> If you select this option, Windows adds the Novell, Inc. certificate
> to the Windows Trusted Publishers certificate list for the current
> Windows machine. The next time this Windows machine encounters driver
> software signed with the same Novell, Inc. certificate, Windows
> proceeds with installation rather than prompting you again for
> confirmation.
>
> > If you want to keep Windows from presenting this installation approval
> > (for the Client or for any other driver software using
> > publisher-signed Authenticode signatures), you can pre-distribute the
> > publisher's public certificate used for Authenticode signing to the
> > Windows machines Trusted Publishers certificate list prior to
> > installation of the driver software.

To follow the path to do it;

> Run CERTMGR.MSC (normally; do not have to force elevation via "Run as
> Administrator").
>
> From the View menu, select Options and enable "Physical certificate
> stores".
>
> Expand "Trusted Publishers" and select/highlight the "Local Computer"
> store.
>
> Right-click on the "Local Computer" store, and from "All Tasks" choose
> "Import".
>
> Browse to the Novell, Inc certificate which had been exported from a
> different Windows machine, and on the "Certificate Store" page of the
> import wizard, ensure "Trusted Publishers\Local Computer" is selected.
>
> Complete the Import wizard, and ensure the Novell, Inc. certificate
> shows under "Trusted Publishers\Local Computer" in the CERTMGR.MSC
> console.The selection of the Local Computer certificate store during
> the certificate import process is what ensures the Novell, Inc.
> certificate is being imported in a way that will be available as a
> Trusted Publisher to the Windows driver installation process. Again,
> this all happens automatically when using the Always trust software
> from Novell, Inc. option during an interactive Client installation.

[Reference](https://www.novell.com/documentation/windows_client/windows_client_admin/data/bqgnrgi.html)